# How can I change xmlns of root tag Envelop in soap request in WCF

Tags: wcf, soap, soap-client

I need to change xmlns of root tag Envelope in soap request in WCF. Like now WCF creating following request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"></s:Envelope>
```

But I need to create like following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:abc="abc.astute.ca/"; xmlns:xyz="xyz.astute.ca/"; xmlns:asd="asd.astute.ca/"; xmlns:qwe="qwe.astute.ca/"; xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not to do it (there is almost never a reason to do it). If this is a requirement than you could do it in a [custom message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx) - you would need to change all places where the prefix is referred to as well.